# run a unix shell command if the output doesn't have a specific number of lines

Tags: shell

I've got a unix command sequence that goes something like:

```
command1 | command2 | command3 | wc -l
```

Now that I have the number of lines, I'd like to do something (run a specific command with no inputs) if the number of lines isn't equal to a specific number.  My shell scripting is fantastically rusty (perhaps 10 years or more since I've done much Unix work) so I don't know how to add this kind of conditional to a command sequence.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda ugly .. but this works.

```
#  test $(seq 10 | wc -l) -eq 10 && echo "there's 10"
there's 10
#  test $(seq 11 | wc -l) -eq 10 && echo "there's 10"
```

nothing's `echo`ed in the second case

Comment: that reminds me of my college days, when our unix programming instructor advised us not to name our compiled programs "test".

Comment: seems I need backticks instead of $() syntax for csh, but otherwise this works great.  thanks.

Comment: You named them? .. I was happy with `a.out` :p

Comment: Now I want a time machine, to get to someone's terminal back in college and add a command to a directory in their path called "a.out" that only sleeps for 2 seconds and prints "core dump".

Answer (score 5):

You need to capture the output of your `wc` command and use `if` to run another command if it's not equal to the number of lines you want, such as:

```
count=$(command1 | command2 | command3 | wc -l)
if [[ $count -ne 19 ]] ; then
    command4
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

```
numberOfLines=$(command1 | command2 | command3 | wc -l)
if [ "${numberOfLines}" == "7" ]; then
    echo "Hooray."
fi
```