# Find command to check no files is created within x minutes

Tags: linux, email, find

I have a NVR system that recording video surveilance into a linux server. This NVR system sometimes stops recordings (Bug) and I wanna know when that happens.

I'm looking into using the find command with a into a script and a cronjob to send me an email if no files is created within the passed 60 minutes.

The command I came up with is:

```
find /path/to/folder/* -name "*.ts" -mmin +0 -mmin -60 -exec echo "No New Recording Available" \; | mail -s "PP-NVR" me@server.com
```

But this command only sends me a list of "No New Recording Available" for the files older than 60 minutes

```
No New Recordinf Available
No New Recordinf Available
No New Recordinf Available
No New Recordinf Available
No New Recordinf Available
...
```

Can anyone please help!

EDIT: This is the script I came up with but it doesn't seem like it's working correctly:

```
#!/bin/sh

if test 'find /path_to_folder/* -name "*.ts" -mmin +1 -mmin -10'
then
echo "No New Recording Available" | mail -s "PP-NVR" me@server.com
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try combining this 
[run a unix shell command if the output doesn't have a specific number of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328811/run-a-unix-shell-command-if-the-output-doesnt-have-a-specific-number-of-lines)

With

```
vagrant@puppet ~]$ find . -name '*.ts' -mmin -1 | wc -l
0
[vagrant@puppet ~]$ touch blah.ts
[vagrant@puppet ~]$ find . -name '*.ts' -mmin -1 | wc -l
1
```

So:

```
[vagrant@puppet ~]$ ./alert.sh
No new files
[vagrant@puppet ~]$ echo >> blah.ts
[vagrant@puppet ~]$ ./alert.sh
[vagrant@puppet ~]$ cat alert.sh
#!/bin/sh

newfiles=$(find . -name '*.ts' -mmin -1 | wc -l)

if [[ $newfiles -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "No new files"
fi
[vagrant@puppet ~]$
```

Comment: Can add the the path to my folder like: newfiles=$(find /pathtofile -name '*.ts' -mmin -1 | wc -l) ?

Comment: I'm getting "./Check2.sh: 5: ./Check2.sh: [[: not found
" Any idea why ?

Comment: What do you get when you run
/bin/sh --version

Also 
uname -a

Comment: Try switch /bin/sh to /bin/bash

Comment: [[ is just a built in alias for 'test'

Comment: is it difficult to convert this script to a nagios plugin

Comment: I  don't see why not.  It's just a generic script.   I think this is a different question though.  Raise a new one with a little like "How do I convert a bash script into a Nagios plugin?"  Or better yet run a quick search. I was able to find some examples easily enough. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I already did but so far no luck. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657539/nagios-plugin-to-check-files-are-created-within-x-minutes

Comment: Hi Youssef I've answered your question there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution using find, but you can use inotifywait (in inotify-tools) to set up a watcher, like this:

```
inotifywait -r -e modify -t 60 /path/to/folder
```

and check $? for the value 2 which means that it has timed out after 60 seconds (-t 60) without files being modified (-e modify) inside the /path/to/folder and it's sub-folders (-r).

Comment: Inotify is a Linux kernel feature.  inotifyway is a utility which uses that feature.  You can install it using your distribution's package management system, e.g. **apt-get install inotify.tools**.